# Does memory leak if I pass a control to a different class for event handling?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, garbage-collection, idisposable

Given that said class both subscribes to the control's events **AND** holds reference to the control.

Background: I have custom scroll panels on a few forms/usercontrols and I decided to extract the scrolling code into a class named "ScrollLogic" so it can be reused. The class constructor is as following:

```vb
Sub New (bntUp as Button, bntDown as Button, panelToScroll as Panel, _
         scrollLength As Integer)

        Me.bntUp = bntUp         'Declaration: Private bntUp As Button     
        AddHandler Me.bntUp.Click, AddressOf UpClicked

       'Setup code for other controls/variables here  

End Sub
```

When a button is clicked, ScrollLogic would scroll panelToScroll via the AutoScrollPosition property. If scroll limit is reached, corresponding button is set to be invisible. (or visible if scrolls in opposite direction becomes possible after scrolling)

It works fine, but I have noticed that

1. ScorllLogic subscribes to click events of the buttons in order to work
2. ScrollLogic holds reference of buttons to control their visibility. Having access to sender of event is insufficient since **bntUp** must be set visible **when bntDown is clicked**.

Does this lead to memory leak? I'm trying to avoid overriding dispose() of every forms/usercontrols affected to dispose ScrollLogic objects because that would be ugly. Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no leak here.  Subscribing the button event(s) creates a reference from the button to your class object, not the other way around.  The reference chain is form => buttons => your object.  So everything is eligible for collection as soon as the user closes the form or you dispose it.

Even if your class held a reference to the buttons (none is evident) then it still doesn't matter, the GC has no problem with circular references.

There's no hint where you store the reference to your class object.  Surely nowhere, none is needed since the buttons are good enough to keep it alive.  Very hard to fumble this, you'd have to do something drastic like storing it in a static variable.  Feel good about it by writing a little test code that creates/shows/disposes the form thousands of times.